# R fastest way to get values from list as vector

Tags: r, dictionary

in R, give a list

```
l1 <- list(a = "A", b = "B", c = "C")
```

and a vector

```
v<- c("a", "c")
```

How to get elements from the list in vector? For example

```
l1[v]
```

returns a list, while I need a vector as

```
c("A", "C")
```

Looking for **fastest** **one-liner**.

Comment: Try `unlist(l1[v],use.names=F)` to drop the names.

Comment: try `unlist(l1[v])`@nrussel your first solution does not work with `l1 <- list(a = c("A","A1"), b = "B", c = "C")`

Comment: Please provide some speed test and put them as answer.

Comment: @d.putto, you could speed test them yourself via the `microbenchmark` or `rbenchmark` packages ...

Answer (score 7):

You can try this, which is similar to @ColonelBeauvel

```
identical(as.vector(unlist(l1[v])), c("A", "C"))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: So both: as.vector(unlist(l1[v])) and unlist(l1[v],use.names=F) are valid solutions. They both produce character atomic arrays of length 2.